# log4net set log file at a relative path

Tags: vb.net, logging, log4net

In my vb.net project, I use log4net and use an absolute path for the log file. But in the end I need to write log file at C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\Log folder (the username is a variable). Can't find a way how to set this in the log4net file.

My log4net file currently like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ExampleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\Log\App.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="_yyyyMMdd" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level - 
            [%logger] %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="App">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="ExampleAppender" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Is there a way to perform this? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use environment variables like this:

```
 <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="${LOCALAPPDATA}\Temp\Log\App.log" />
```

This creates a log file (for me) at `C:\Users\stuartd\AppData\Local\Temp\Log\App.log`

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. Don't know why I still cannot get the log file in the specified folder, is there anything else to set?

Comment: I've run a quick test on your config with the changes, and it creates and writes to a file: note that with your current configuration your logger *must* be called "App" in order to write log entries, as you have not defined a root element. If you are running this in a web application, the app pool identity may not have the permissions to write to `${LOCALAPPDATA}`

Comment: Hello stuartd, it is a desktop application, thank you.

Comment: Hi stuartd, I found a strange thing, even I change to another absolute path, it still write into the previous folder (C:\Log\) even though I already rebuild the project.

Comment: Hi stuartd, there is something wrong with my app.config. After fix it, the log file is successfully written into user's temp folder, thanks a lot.